# Nginx not serving static content over rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, routes

I want to serve static images with nginx. I have in my nginx.conf

```
location /i/ {
      alias /home/matt/images/;
}
```

I am going to `server.com/i/928675140291b6.jpg` Just to see if it will serve the image, But I'm getting in `production.log`:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/i/928675140291b6.jpg"):`

The response to `curl -I server.com/i/928675140291b6.jpg`:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 13:49:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1564
Connection: keep-alive
X-Request-Id: abb0cb6c-e922-4186-b245-e78b21a88919
X-Runtime: 0.007451
```

Comment: What's the response headers for this request? (i.e `curl -I http://server.com/i/928675140291b6.jpg`)

Comment: @KeenanLawrence I've updated my question with the response

Comment: You sure the image exists at `/home/matt/images/928675140291b6.jpg`?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Yes

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your situation and it's working perfectly for me. I know this sounds silly, but have you restarted nginx after making the changes? This request shouldn't even hit the backend (ROR)

Comment: @KeenanLawrence I have restarted, I have no idea why the requests are going to rails first and not nginx. So weird

Comment: @KeenanLawrence I typed i ran `nginx` on my server and I got `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126531/discussion-between-keenan-lawrence-and-matt-bettinson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, for some reason, nginx doesen't care about the `nginx.conf` in my Rails project folder. I edited the file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app` and now nginx is listening.